# Возможно ли сверстать такое модальное окно?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли сверстать такое модальное окно на чистом html css?
В макете на десктоп версии модальное окно полностью перекрывает остальные элементы интерфейса, однако на мобильной версии окно встраивается в интерфейс таким образом будто это обычный блок на странице, но при этом это модальное окно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _"Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли сверстать такое модальное окно на чистом html css?"_ Да,  такое возможно.

Comment: @UModeL не подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: если это обычный блок - то он уже не модальное окно. На второй картинке в вопросе показывается все еще модальное окно.

Comment: @JoelKamp: это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @UModeL спасибо

Comment: @Grundy да, это модальное окно, но я не могу понять каким образом на мобильном экране можно оставить навбар и футер на своих местах а контент убрать под модалку

Comment: просто бэкдроп растягиваешь не на весь экран, в с учетом верха и низа. Плюс, непонятно, с чего ты взял, что _на мобильном экране **нужно** оставить навбар и футер на своих местах_

Comment: @Grundy в дизайне навбар и футер на своих местах

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ плохой дизайн, если модальное окно не является модальным :) Но на картинке в вопросе - этого не видно.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос..
Блок будет модалкой на больших экранах, а на экране `<768px` (можно редактировать), будет как обычный элемент:

```css
p {
 white-space: pre; 
}

.modal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9990;
}

.modal__wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 240px;
  min-height: 320px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .modal {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: static;
  }
  
  .modal__wrap {
    min-width: auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Вот она, вот она -
Наших душ глубина,
В ней два сердца плывут, как одно, -
Пора занавесить окно.</p>

<p>Пусть в нашем прошлом будут рыться люди странные,
И пусть сочтут они, что стоит все его приданное, -
Давно назначена цена
И за обоих внесена -
Одна любовь, любовь одна.</p>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal__wrap">
    <h1>Содержимое модалки</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Холодна, холодна
Голых стен белизна, -
Но два сердца стучат, как одно,
И греют, и — настежь окно!</p>

<p>Но перестал дарить цветы он просто так, не к случаю,
Любую женщину в кафе теперь считает лучшею.
И улыбается она
Случайным людям у окна,
И привыкает засыпать одна.</p>
```

Comment: Минус без причины - признак дурачины. Оставляйте комментарий хоть.

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю зачем минусанули ответ и при этом ничего не написав

Comment: @JoelKamp, а Вам ответ помог, или есть уточнения?

Comment: не, ответ не помог, пришлось по-другому колдовать

Comment: @JoelKamp, вы можете писать что не так и я изменю ответ

Comment: @De.Minov +1 за старания